# codeigniter error but works fine on my local server

Tags: codeigniter, controller

Hello all im working on a project but when i upload my project i got a error you can see here

http://rapcom.dk/profil/index/KoS

but i think im doing it work cause it works on my local PC :S, here is my controller

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('profil_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->profil_model->vis_profil($this->uri->segment(3)); 


    //Henter lib profilwall så man kan vise wall beskeder i profilen
    $this->load->library('profilewall');
    $data['queryWall'] = $this->profilewall->wallShow();


    $this->template->write_view('content', 'profil_view', $data);
    $this->template->render();
}
```

And my library called profileWall.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Profilewall
{

    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function wallShow()
    {
        $this->CI->load->model('profil_model');
        return $this->CI->profil_model->wallGet($this->CI->uri->segment(3));
    }
}
```

do you know what can be wrong? and im 100% sure it is uploaded du the server

Comment: Did you remember to change `$config['base_url']` in config.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have to do with how you are naming the actual file. Could you try naming the file *profilewall.php* rather than *profileWall.php* and see if that works.

For the most part you should be mindful of case issues, especially with CodeIgniter. Generally the rule of thumb is to use lowercase characters in filenames, models, etc.

Comment: Thanks you so much! :d i just think i have done that :d but it works now :) thx